# kivy app works on computer but not mobile device

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I made a kivy app and ran it on my computer and it works well, i pack it and put it on my android phone and it closes immediately. Also note that i am using the PyCharm IDE

i read another forum and one guy said check for breakpoints, but i have no breakpoints set. the way that i am calling the .kv file is through "name convention" as you will see in the code

main.py:

```
import socket
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Make_Client(FloatLayout):
    ...

class ClientApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Make_Client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ClientApp().run()
```

---

client.kv:

```
# File name: main.py

<FloatLayout>:
   ...
```

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: i ran the debugger, did'nt do anything for a while so i started the app and just as it closed i stopped the debugger to read the console and noticed it said "socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied" but why would the socket permission be denied it's on the local network, and it worked when i put the application on another computer on my network but it wont work on my phone

Comment: Android requires permissions for just about everything. To use the internet you need permission. In your `buildozer.spec` file add a line: `android.permissions = INTERNET`. Then see what other permissions you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a friend and he told me it was the "Android-Manifest.xml"
so in my APK packer (buildozer) i had to tell it to ask for the android.permissions.INTERNET and then my app worked on my phone