# my kivy app is all right on my computer, but don't show its content on my phone

Tags: python, android, sqlite, logging, kivy

My kivy project can run correctly on my computer, but if I use package **logging** to log, the project will not `start application main loop` on my phone. The following is my main.py:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import sqlite3
import logging.config

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from plyer import email, storagepath, uniqueid

from sql import sql_create_table, sql_select_example, sql_insert_example, sql_select_records, sql_disable_record, \
    sql_insert_arecord

# replace default font
resource_add_path(os.path.abspath('./font'))
LabelBase.register('Roboto', 'MSYH.TTC')

# basic info here
app_version = '1.0.1'
db_filepath = 'records.db'
logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')

# Loading Multiple .kv files
# Builder.load_file('screenkv/feedback.kv')
Builder.load_file('screenkv/records.kv')
Builder.load_file('screenkv/arecord.kv')
Builder.load_file('screenkv/information.kv')
Builder.load_file('screenkv/experiment.kv')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def goto_information(self):
        self.manager.current = 'information'

    def goto_records(self):
        self.manager.current = 'records'

    def goto_feedback(self):
        app_path = storagepath.get_application_dir()
        device_id = uniqueid.get_uid()
        email.send(recipient='18146856052@163.com',
                   subject='app test',
                   text='应用版本: ' + app_version + '\n'
                        '保存路径: ' + app_path + '\n'
                        '设备ID: ' + device_id + '\n\n\n'
                        '其它: \n',
                   create_chooser=True)


# Declare RecordsScreen in kv
class RecordsScreen(Screen):
    ...


# Declare ARecordScreen in kv
class ARecordScreen(Screen):
    ...


# Declare ExperimentScreen in kv
class ExperimentScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MicroApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Kivy supports only 1 window per application
        # Window.size = (360, 792)
        self.title = 'micro-GCFP'
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The name of the kv file must match the part before the App ending.
    # e.g. pongApp -> pong.kv
    try:
        MicroApp().run()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
```

Only after I delete all the logging-related code, it will start application main loop on my phone. But it does not show its content and naturally I can not operate it. The following is what I got from running `adb logcat *:S python:D`:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
04-07 22:02:05.777 21707 25848 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
04-07 22:02:05.777 21707 25848 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
04-07 22:02:05.777 21707 25848 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
04-07 22:02:05.777 21707 25848 I python  : /data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app
04-07 22:02:05.784 21707 25848 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
04-07 22:02:05.784 21707 25848 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
04-07 22:02:05.784 21707 25848 I python  : calculated paths to be...
04-07 22:02:05.784 21707 25848 I python  : /data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
04-07 22:02:05.786 21707 25848 I python  : set wchar paths...
04-07 22:02:05.814 21707 25848 I python  : Initialized python
04-07 22:02:05.814 21707 25848 I python  : AND: Init threads
04-07 22:02:05.815 21707 25848 I python  : testing python print redirection
04-07 22:02:05.815 21707 25848 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
04-07 22:02:05.816 21707 25848 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/system/sbin:/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.runtime', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/featurelayer-widget.jar:/system/framework/hwEmui.jar:/system/framework/hwPartBasicplatform.jar:/system/framework/telephony-separated.jar:/system/framework/hwTelephony-common.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephony.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyVSim.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyCust.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyFullnetworkOpt.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyTimezoneOpt.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyOpt.jar:/system/framework/hwPartSecurity.jar:/system/framework/hwPartSecurityFaceId.jar:/system/framework/hwIms-common.jar:/system/framework/hwPartMedia.jar:/system/framework/hwPartConnectivity.jar:/system/framework/hwPartPowerOffice.jar:/system/framework/hwPartDeviceVirtualization.jar:/system/framework/hwPartAirSharing.jar:/system/framework/hwPartDefaultDFR.jar:/system/framework/hwPartDFR.jar:/system/framework/hwPartMagicWindow.jar:/system/framework/hwPartIaware.jar:/system/framework/hwPartMdm.jar:/system/framework/hwPartVr.jar:/system/framework/hwframework.jar:/system/framework/com.huawei.nfc.jar:/system/framework/org.ifaa.android.manager.jar:/system/framework/hwperf.jar:/system/framework/hwcustEmui.jar:/system/framework/hwcustframework.jar:/system/framework/servicehost.jar:/system/framework/hwcustIms-common.jar:/system/framework/hwcustTelephony-common.jar:/system/framework/hwIAwareAL.jar:/system/framework/zframework.z.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/featurelayer-widget.jar:/system/framework/hwEmui.jar:/system/framework/hwPartBasicplatform.jar:/system/framework/telephony-separated.jar:/system/framework/hwTelephony-common.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephony.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyVSim.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyCust.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyFullnetworkOpt.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyTimezoneOpt.jar:/system/framework/hwPartTelephonyOpt.jar:/system/framework/hwPartSecurity.jar:/system/framework/hwPartSecurityFaceId.jar:/system/framework/hwIms-common.jar:/system/framework/hwPartMedia.jar:/system/framework/hwPartConnectivity.jar:/system/framework/hwPartPowerOffice.jar:/system/framework/hwPartDeviceVirtualization.jar:/system/framework/hwPartAirSharing.jar:/system/framework/hwPartDefaultDFR.jar:/system/framework/hwPartDFR.jar:/system/framework/hwPartMagicWindow.jar:/system/framework/hwPartIaware.jar:/system/framework/hwPartMdm.jar:/system/framework/hwPartVr.jar:/system/framework/hwframework.jar:/system/framework/com.huawei.nfc.jar:/system/framework/org.ifaa.android.manager.jar:/system/framework/hwperf.jar:/system/framework/hwcustEmui.jar:/
04-07 22:02:05.816 21707 25848 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
04-07 22:02:05.816 21707 25848 I python  : AND: Ran string
04-07 22:02:05.816 21707 25848 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
04-07 22:02:05.899 21707 25848 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 24)
04-07 22:02:05.900 21707 25848 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
04-07 22:02:05.903 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-04-07_0.txt
04-07 22:02:05.903 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
04-07 22:02:05.904 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/scu.uni.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
04-07 22:02:05.904 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.9 (default, Apr  4 2022, 13:26:04)
04-07 22:02:05.904 21707 25848 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
04-07 22:02:05.904 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
04-07 22:02:05.904 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
04-07 22:02:05.904 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
04-07 22:02:06.290 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
04-07 22:02:06.419 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
04-07 22:02:06.433 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
04-07 22:02:06.446 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
04-07 22:02:06.460 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
04-07 22:02:06.461 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
04-07 22:02:06.461 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r18p0-01rel0.e407b90de3ca665076bcf462325ff5ad'>
04-07 22:02:06.461 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
04-07 22:02:06.461 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G76'>
04-07 22:02:06.461 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
04-07 22:02:06.462 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
04-07 22:02:06.462 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
04-07 22:02:06.484 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
04-07 22:02:06.485 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
04-07 22:02:06.538 21707 25848 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
04-07 22:02:06.539 21707 25848 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

I have tried to change my db_path to `'../records.db'`, or delete following 2 linee which replace the default font:

```
resource_add_path(os.path.abspath('./font'))
LabelBase.register('Roboto', 'MSYH.TTC')
```

But they do not work. My buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = microapp

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = scu.uni

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = microApp/

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
# !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!rememember to update here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttc,ttf,conf,db

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.5

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
# !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!remember to update here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
# No need to add logging, sqlite3
requirements = python3,kivy,plyer
# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/pics/growthcurve.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.1.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, READ_SYNC_SETTINGS, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

The reason I do not add `logging` or `sqlite3` in my requirments is that one told me python had contained them and it could not be package when I added `logging`.
The following is the result of `adb logcat | find "scu.uni.myapp"`:

```
04-07 22:01:40.309  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: onPackageInstallStateUpdate uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,packageAddFlag=0
04-07 22:01:40.313  2593  2593 I HwKeystoreServiceImpl: package removed for update, packageName:scu.uni.myapp appId:10281
04-07 22:01:40.322  2593  2593 D DEF_PackageChangedBroadcastReceiver: onReceive scu.uni.myapp android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED replacing: true
04-07 22:01:40.621  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: onPackageInstallStateUpdate uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,packageAddFlag=1
04-07 22:01:40.661  2593  2593 D DEF_PackageChangedBroadcastReceiver: onReceive scu.uni.myapp android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED replacing: true
04-07 22:01:41.009  2593  2593 D DEF_PackageChangedBroadcastReceiver: onReceive scu.uni.myapp android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED replacing: true
04-07 22:02:03.240 21707 21707 W ActivityThread: Application scu.uni.myapp can be debugged on port 8100...
04-07 22:02:03.324 21707 21707 D ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{1593ad9 token=android.os.BinderProxy@765af25 {scu.uni.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@765af25
04-07 22:02:03.347  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidAdd uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp activity state: true
04-07 22:02:03.347  2593  3191 I UidCloseNrStateMachine: enter uidStateChanged, ForeGrountApp=scu.uni.myapp, mIsCallOn=false, mIsUsbPlugged=true, openLowPowerSwitch=true, lteQoeSlowState=false, powerPerformanceMode=2, isOpenAreaSaSwitch=false, isSpeedSensitivityApp=false, mIsCloseLowPowerByAreaSwitch=false
04-07 22:02:03.349  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:03.350  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:03.350  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=FOREGROUND
04-07 22:02:03.351  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:03.453  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:03.453  2593  3191 I Power2r4rHandover: 4rTo2rCondition, usbStatus = true, foreGrountApp = scu.uni.myapp, 4rTo2rCtrlRule = 1, is4rTo2rCheck = false, batteryMode = 1, mIs4r2rHandover = false
04-07 22:02:03.453  2593  3191 E ScgQuickAddManager: the compName is :scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:03.454  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp class:org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:03.454  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:03.739  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: sendKernelAppUid, Uid = 10281, period = 2000 name = scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:03.741  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:18.866  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidRemove uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:18.867  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:18.868  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:18.868  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=BACKGROUND
04-07 22:02:18.868  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:18.868  2593  3191 I DollieChr: handleForegroundAppUpdateMsg,mAppState=2,scenes=1,mForegroundAppName=scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:18.869  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:19.678  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidAdd uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp activity state: true
04-07 22:02:19.687  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: sendKernelAppUid, Uid = 10281, period = 2000 name = scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:19.689  2593  3191 I UidCloseNrStateMachine: UID hot switch, uid:10281, pkgName:scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:19.694  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:19.695  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:19.696  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=FOREGROUND
04-07 22:02:19.697  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:19.735  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:19.736  2593  3191 I Power2r4rHandover: 4rTo2rCondition, usbStatus = true, foreGrountApp = scu.uni.myapp, 4rTo2rCtrlRule = 1, is4rTo2rCheck = false, batteryMode = 1, mIs4r2rHandover = false
04-07 22:02:19.736  2593  3191 E ScgQuickAddManager: the compName is :scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:19.736  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp class:org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:19.736  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:21.141  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidRemove uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:21.142  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.142  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.142  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=BACKGROUND
04-07 22:02:21.143  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.143  2593  3191 I DollieChr: handleForegroundAppUpdateMsg,mAppState=2,scenes=1,mForegroundAppName=scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:21.145  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.311  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidAdd uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp activity state: true
04-07 22:02:21.332  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: sendKernelAppUid, Uid = 10281, period = 2000 name = scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:21.335  2593  3191 I UidCloseNrStateMachine: UID hot switch, uid:10281, pkgName:scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:21.337  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.340  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.341  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=FOREGROUND
04-07 22:02:21.342  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.376  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:21.376  2593  3191 I Power2r4rHandover: 4rTo2rCondition, usbStatus = true, foreGrountApp = scu.uni.myapp, 4rTo2rCtrlRule = 1, is4rTo2rCheck = false, batteryMode = 1, mIs4r2rHandover = false
04-07 22:02:21.376  2593  3191 E ScgQuickAddManager: the compName is :scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:21.377  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp class:org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:21.377  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:26.044  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidRemove uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:26.049  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.049  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.049  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=BACKGROUND
04-07 22:02:26.050  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.050  2593  3191 I DollieChr: handleForegroundAppUpdateMsg,mAppState=2,scenes=1,mForegroundAppName=scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:26.052  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.247  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidAdd uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp activity state: true
04-07 22:02:26.254  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: sendKernelAppUid, Uid = 10281, period = 2000 name = scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:26.258  2593  3191 I UidCloseNrStateMachine: UID hot switch, uid:10281, pkgName:scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:26.269  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.271  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.271  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=FOREGROUND
04-07 22:02:26.277  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.311  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:26.311  2593  3191 I Power2r4rHandover: 4rTo2rCondition, usbStatus = true, foreGrountApp = scu.uni.myapp, 4rTo2rCtrlRule = 1, is4rTo2rCheck = false, batteryMode = 1, mIs4r2rHandover = false
04-07 22:02:26.311  2593  3191 E ScgQuickAddManager: the compName is :scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:26.311  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp class:org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:26.311  2593  3191 I VideoEnhancing: pkg:scu.uni.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 22:02:52.810  2593  3191 I HidataAppQoeP: foregroundUidRemove uid: 10281 name: scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:52.812  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:52.813  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:52.813  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardSM: onUidStateUpdate,uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,state=BACKGROUND
04-07 22:02:52.813  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:52.814  2593  3191 I DollieChr: handleForegroundAppUpdateMsg,mAppState=2,scenes=1,mForegroundAppName=scu.uni.myapp
04-07 22:02:52.824  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: getAppType,pkgName=scu.uni.myapp,appType=-1
04-07 22:02:53.117  2593  2593 I HwCoreAppHelperService: LocalReceiver receives:android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED,pkg:scu.uni.myapp,uid:10281
04-07 22:02:58.039  2593  3191 I SmartDualCardConfig: onPackageInstallStateUpdate uid=10281,appName=scu.uni.myapp,packageAddFlag=0
04-07 22:02:58.104  2593  2593 I HwKeystoreServiceImpl: ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED userId:0 appId:10281 packageName:scu.uni.myapp removeAll:true
04-07 22:02:58.126  2593  2593 D DEF_PackageChangedBroadcastReceiver: onReceive scu.uni.myapp android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED replacing: false
```

So anyone can help me? I have applied [Kivy app not working on phone but works on Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67108168/kivy-app-not-working-on-phone-but-works-on-computer#new-answer) and [kivy app works on computer but not mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947229/kivy-app-works-on-computer-but-not-mobile-device), but it did not work...

Comment: And I have tried to delete almost everything from my code, but their results are all same. BUT when I package the pong game example, it displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

kivy supports

```
def build(self):
        self.title = 'micro-GCFP'
        return
```

on windows, but when on Android, you have to return something, a screen or a screenmanager.